# How to show column "Run as" user in Databricks workflows "Job runs" tab

Tags: azure-databricks

Is it possible to change the user/email that runs the spark jobs on Azure Databricks?

I have followed below steps:

1. Created two users finance, humanresource in Azure AD.
2. Created databricks service and created cluster, notebook and job.
3. Synched above users into databricks using Azure Databricks SCIM enterprise app so that above users available in workspace.
4. Kept permissions for users like devanand.dhage_gmail.com#ext#@.... as owner and financeuser@... as Can Manage Run.
5. I Ran my web api and called /api/2.1/jobs/run-now using financeuser@... token.

What I expect is in Databricks worksflows page under Job runs I must get financeuser@... name instead of Owners name. How to achieve this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGKeY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Job runs list displays:

•   The start time for the run.

•   The name of the job associated with the run.

•   The user name that the job runs as.

•   Whether the run was triggered by a job schedule or an API request, or was manually started.

•   The time elapsed for a currently running job, or the total running time for a completed run.

•   The status of the run, either Pending, Running, Skipped, Succeeded, Failed, Terminating, Terminated, Internal Error, Timed Out, Canceled, Canceling, or Waiting for Retry.

**Run as : When this job runs, it will use the job creator's permissions. It will not show who is running this job.** This is about who created Job.
[image]

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-engineering/jobs/jobs#--view-recent-job-runs

Comment: If I want to achieve the same thing as discussed in the question i.e. I want to show the job runner's name then what will be the solution?

Comment: Try creating JOB by financeuser@

Comment: Then it will be static solution for this problem. Actually I want dynamic solution. Anyways thank you for your support.